# Logback.xml configuration by environment

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, environment-variables, logback, graylog

I have logback configuration which is like bellow, as you can see i have an appender that appends all the logs to the standalone logging service.

```
<appender name="digitalGelfAppender" 
 class="de.siegmar.logbackgelf.GelfUdpAppender">
    <graylogHost>testserver.loggingservice.com</graylogHost>
    <graylogPort>1234</graylogPort>
    <useCompression>true</useCompression>
    <layout class="de.siegmar.logbackgelf.GelfLayout">
        <originHost>originHost</originHost>
        <includeRawMessage>false</includeRawMessage>
        <includeMarker>true</includeMarker>
        <includeMdcData>true</includeMdcData>
        <includeCallerData>false</includeCallerData>
        <includeRootCauseData>false</includeRootCauseData>
        <includeLevelName>false</includeLevelName>
        <shortPatternLayout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
        </shortPatternLayout>
        <fullPatternLayout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
        </fullPatternLayout>
        <staticField>application:DAP</staticField>
        <staticField>environment:UAT</staticField>
    </layout>
</appender>

<root level="#logback.loglevel#">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="digitalGelfAppender"/>
</root>
```

My question is that i need to change

```
<graylogHost>testserver.loggingservice.com</graylogHost>
<graylogPort>1234</graylogPort>
```

by environment value. So it will be like bellow on production server.

```
<graylogHost>prodserver.loggingservice.com</graylogHost>
<graylogPort>prodPort</graylogPort>
```

How can i pass the environment value to the logback.xml file by environment?
I tried to add these variables and use it like property inside xml. Its not working at all.

```
<property name="GRAYLOG_SERVER" value="${graylog-hostname}" />
<property name="GRAYLOG_SERVER_PORT" value="{graylog-port}" />
```

Usage

```
<graylogHost>${GRAYLOG_SERVER}</graylogHost>
<graylogPort>${GRAYLOG_SERVER_PORT}</graylogPort>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi i solve my problem by implementing listener that retrieve data from System parameter of environment;

```
@Controller
public class LoggerContextListener extends ContextAwareBase implements 
LoggerContextListener, LifeCycle {


@Override
public void start() {   
                Map<String, String> property = System.getenv();
                Context context = getContext();
                context.putProperty("GRAYLOG_SERVER", property.get("graylog-hostname"));
                context.putProperty("GRAYLOG_SERVER_PORT", property.get("graylog-port"));
}
```

After that i add that listener as a contextListener to the lockback.xml

```
<contextListener class="com.anadolusigorta.dap.config.DapLoggerContextListener"/>
```

Then problem solved! Now my xml can use these parameter that set from listener;

```
<graylogHost>${GRAYLOG_SERVER}</graylogHost>
<graylogPort>${GRAYLOG_SERVER_PORT}</graylogPort>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the listener. It is enough that use the environment variables as follows.

```
 <graylogHost>${graylog-hostname}</graylogHost>
 <graylogPort>${graylog-port}</graylogPort>
```